# How do i add the word "chat" before ,in the lines that contain ":Cc:" with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I want to add the word "chat" before to the lines that contain ":Cc:" how do i do this with a awk command

Comment: What do you mean by the word 'before'? I suggest you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14844469/edit) your question to include some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk '/:Cc:/ { printf "chat" } { print }'` and see if it does what you are looking for.